# how to make my image go from right to left with animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i wanna make the images go from right to left on my screen, but it has to be like a rainbow so in the middle it goes up and goes down but i cant get the rainbow effect i tried to play with the numbers to make sure when its at the middle its goes up and down but it does not give the rainbow effect

```
 .imaga{
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1000px;
  }

  @keyframes imgcards {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);    }
    25% {
        transform: translate(-500px, 50px);    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(-1000px, 70px);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translate(-1500px, -50px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-2000px, 0);
    }
}


.imaga .imgcards {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: imgcards 13s linear infinite;

}
```

Comment: Could you ple add your HTML code

Answer (score 2):

I changed keyframes values to this and it is working but not sure about your exact requirement because of missing html

```
 .imaga{
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1000px;
  }

@keyframes imgcards {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
  }
}

.imaga .imgcards {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: imgcards 13s linear infinite;

}
```

```css
 .imaga{
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1000px;
  }

@keyframes imgcards {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
  }
}

.imaga .imgcards {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: imgcards 13s linear infinite;

}
```

```html
<div class="imaga">
  <div class="imgcards">Krusshnaaaa</div>
</div>
```